# Rails javascript calls after partial rendered

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What's the right place to put javascript/coffeescript in Rails when working with partial being loaded via AJAX?

I would like to call:

```
$('.selector').datapicker()
```

every time '_form' partial is loaded.

I can put this directly into the `_form.html.erb` partial and it would work like expected but I kinda feel like it's a wrong holder for js.

Answer (score 3):

The 'right place' should be within the assets folder where all js scripts reside.

You can use:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
    $('.selector').datapicker();
});
```

Comment: I don't think that I should trigger that js on every AJAX call

Comment: Trigger it on your ajax call complete function then:
$.ajax({
  url: "your_url"
  }).done(function() {
  $('.selector').datapicker();
});

Comment: sorry, but explicitly determining js to run per URL doesn't sound like a good idea

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UJS data-remote to do the ajax, you can hook on to the ajax event that UJS makes.  See here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

use `ajax:complete` to re-add datapicker to the element eg:

```
$('#submitted_form').on('ajax:complete', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  $('#date_field').datapicker();
});
```

...and then this would go in your assets/javascript folder.

Also check out this article: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/